# SQL query: Can't order by column called "order"?

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I am pulling a column in an existing script into my template files, and everything is working great.

The only problem is, that this script has a column called `order`, and every row then has a number in that column to show which should be at the top etc. If I set my query to "`ORDER BY name`" for example, everything works fine, but when I use "`ORDER BY order`", then I get a SQL error.
Can I not have a column called `order`? I can't change column name, because it's part of the script.

Is there a way around it?

This is the line in my SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE hide = 0 ORDER BY order
```

Comment: Try using a table identifier (categories.order). You don't state which DBMS are you using but it probably related to the fact there are reserved words which cannot be used

Comment: What database engine are you using? Alfabravo is almost certainly correct, but the way to quote a reserved word is different in MySQL (backticks), SQL Server (brackets), Oracle (double quotes) etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`order` is a keyword in SQL. So if you wish to use a keyword as a name, use backtick characters around it:

```sql
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE hide = 0 ORDER BY `order`
```

Try that :)

Comment: FYI: This also goes for any keywords. E.g. if you had a column called 'select' (which is also a keyword), you could use backticks for that too.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with Postgres just use "column_name", e.g:

```
SELECT "order" FROM table_name WHERE "order" > 10 ORDER BY "order";
```

Answer (score 1):

AS `order`is a SQL keyword, you should escape it properly as an field identifier by using backticks:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER by `order`
```

Comment: Works for MySql!

Answer (score 0):

Try using backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `hide` = 0 ORDER BY `order`
```

ORDER is a reserved word in SQL.  You can use a reserved word as a column name but you must surround it in backticks when referencing it.  It's good practice to surround all your column names in backticks so you don't run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using back ticks around the column name, that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html):

> A reserved word can be used as an identifier if you quote it.

So you can use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE hide = 0 ORDER BY `order`
```

Comment: How do you know that the OP is using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with brackets. SELECT T.* FROM dbo.test AS T ORDER BY [T].[ORDER]